# Dynamically add like operators in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-like

Can anyone give me a solution for my problem?

I have a string array of max length. I want to compare all of my string array elements with a single SQL query. How can I do that?

```
string[] new = searchtext;
select Qid from questions where qdescriptions like string[0],string[1],string[2]
```

The string array length is not fixed, it's dynamic.

Ex: my search string is "admin login error"

Then I split that into

```
admin
login
error
```

as three parts. My expected result should contain all these three strings in database

Like this

```
Admin post this;
password change for login;
the error database;
```

Hope you understand. The results should contain all my search strings in a single search query..

C# code:

```
 public void searchdetails(string[] searchwords) { 
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(); 
     con.ConnectionString = connection; con.Open(); 

     string[] soldesc = searchwords; 
     int i = 0; 

     if (soldesc.Length == 1) { 
        string query1 = "select Qid from Questions where Qdescription like '% " + soldesc[i] + " %'"; 
     }

     SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(query1, con); cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Please provide some more details

Comment: look it now ..ii have updated

Comment: You need one LIKE per string, put OR between the LIKE's.

Comment: string array in sql?

Comment: Which dbms product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by dynamically creating your sql query:

```
 string[] new = searchtext;
 String query = "select Qid from questions";
```

Write a for loop in your application that loops through your search array:
Pseudo code incoming:

```
For(String searchstring in new){
   if(new.indexof(searchstring) === 0){
      query += " where qdescriptions like " + searchstring;
   }
   else{
   //depending on what you want to do here use OR or AND
      query += " or qdescriptions like " + searchstring;
   }

}

result = query.execute();
```

Note: this is pseudo code, seeing as you didn't say what programming language etc you are using I can't tell you what the actual syntax for the for loop will be like or how to protect your query from sqlInjection

Your C# code should look something like this:

```
 public void searchdetails(string[] searchwords) { 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(); con.ConnectionString = connection; 
    con.Open(); 
    string[] soldesc = searchwords;
    string query1 =  "select Qid from Questions";
    For(int i = 0; i<soldesc.Length;i++){
       if (i == 0) { 
         query1 +=  "where Qdescription like '%" + soldesc[i] + "%'";
       }
       else{
         query1 += " AND Qdescription like '%" + soldesc[i] + "%'";
       }
    }


SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(query1, con); cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: jeremy what exactly you posted was i tried..but the problem is i need to split my search string with space then i need to apply the like condition for all splited strings.that splited strings may vary every time ..can you help me out in that scenario.

Comment: could you put an example in your post (use the edit feature, add example data and add expected result)

Comment: basically what you need to do is change the OR in my dynamic query to AND and then it should work, if you somehow convert your single string like 'password change for login' into an array of strings like {'password','change','for','login'} (might be hard or easy depending on which language you are programming in)

Comment: @nanthakumar if you tell me what language you are programming in I might be able to help you out better, and if you give me the code of your application for this feature that you have so far it might go even better

Comment: am using C# ..my code is  public void searchdetails(string[] searchwords)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connection;
            con.Open();
            string[] soldesc = searchwords;
            int i = 0;
            if (soldesc.Length == 1)
            {
                string query1 = "select Qid from Questions where Qdescription like '% " + soldesc[i] + " %'";
                SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
                cmds.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

Comment: jeremy check it for now.

Comment: @nanthakumar you aren't doing a for loop, let me edit your code for you (I must add I haven't written any C# in ages so bear with me)

Comment: @nanthakumar I wrote it as best as I could but not sure about C# syntax I haven't written it in ages

Comment: most other languages have similar syntax so it's not that hard, i've been writing php for a while now so loops and if structures are really similar, I'm happy I was able to help with my limited knowledge of C# though :D

Comment: @ jeremy thanks a lot..it workes with some syntax corrections in C#..You have done a great job eventhough you haven't written C# in ages..

Comment: @ jeremy  really it was so hard to struggle with this issues for the past two days.now am happy.thank u ..

Comment: i want insert <> symbols in sql .how do i can insert?can you help me out?

Comment: if you mean in a string do it like this: '\<\>' ESCAPE '\';  Look up Escape characters in your version of sql (not sure what you are using but the syntax up here works for oracle sql)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
declare @searchtext nvarchar(max) = 'abc,def,pqr'
```

create a function

```
 CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK 
      END 
    IF (@index > 1) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
    END
  RETURN
END
```

Query

```
select * from yourtable y inner join (select value from 
fn_split(@searchtext,',')) as split on y.qdescriptions  like '%+split.value+%'
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for? (Note that the question has no dbms specified.)

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you could generate the query text like this...

```
public static void Main()
{
    string final = GenerateParameters("tableName", "fieldName", new[] {"admin", "login", " error"});

    // execute query
    // final = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE fieldName LIKE '%admin%' OR fieldName LIKE '%login%' OR fieldName LIKE '% error%'"
}

static string GenerateParameters(string tableName, string fieldName, IEnumerable<string> searchTerms)
{            
    string sqlParameters = string.Join(" OR ", searchTerms.Select(x => "{0} LIKE '%{1}%'".FormatWith(fieldName, x)));
    return "SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE ".FormatWith(tableName) + sqlParameters;            
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string FormatWith(this string value, params object[] args)
    {
        return String.Format(value, args);
    }
}
```